# Why macOS IKEv2 client get no reply through tunnel?

Tags: macos, ipsec, strongswan

server: Debian buster (4.19); Strongswan 5.7.2

`ipsec.conf`

```
conn %default
 keyexchange=ikev2
 ike=aes256-aes128-sha256-sha1-modp3072-modp2048-modp1024
 esp=aes256-sha1-ecp256
 fragmentation=yes
 rekey=no
 compress=yes
 dpdaction=clear
 left=100.200.100.200
 leftauth=pubkey
 leftid=@mydnsname.com
 leftcert=server.pem
 leftsendcert=always
 leftsubnet=10.0.0.0/16
 leftfirewall=yes
 lefthostaccess=yes
 right=%any
 rightauth=pubkey
 rightsourceip=10.10.0.0/16
 rightdns=10.0.89.1

conn ikev2-pubkey
 auto=add
```

Linux and Windows clients works well.
For example I can see pings from client to server like this:

```
19:50:18.075816 IP me.59547 > server.4500: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0xcbb1e4ea,seq=0x32b), length 132
19:50:18.076105 IP server.4500 > me.59547: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0xc14e4d72,seq=0x329), length 132
```

with tunnel status:

```
ikev2-pubkey[439]: ESTABLISHED 26 minutes ago, 100.200.100.200[mydnsnmae.com]...150.160.150.160[me]
ikev2-pubkey{331}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 177, ESP in UDP SPIs: cbb1e4ea_i c14e4d72_o
ikev2-pubkey{331}:   10.0.0.0/16 === 10.10.0.1/32
```

But with macOS (Catalina) things goes other way. I have successfully established connection:

```
ikev2-pubkey[442]: ESTABLISHED 7 minutes ago, 100.200.100.200[mydnsnmae.com]...130.120.130.120[me-mac]
ikev2-pubkey{334}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 176, ESP SPIs: c6ba543e_i 03ba0a5a_o
ikev2-pubkey{334}:   10.0.0.0/16 === 10.10.0.4/32
```

And see only one way packets:

```
20:01:27.933739 IP 150.160.150.160 > 100.200.100.200: ESP(spi=0xc632be22,seq=0x5f), length 392
20:01:29.073710 IP 150.160.150.160 > 100.200.100.200: ESP(spi=0xc632be22,seq=0x60), length 392
20:01:29.231101 IP 150.160.150.160 > 100.200.100.200: ESP(spi=0xc632be22,seq=0x61), length 392
20:01:34.683591 IP 100.200.100.200.4500 > 150.160.150.160.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa  inf2
20:01:34.696358 IP 150.160.150.160.4500 > 100.200.100.200.4500: NONESP-encap: isakmp: child_sa  inf2[IR]
20:01:41.563563 IP 150.160.150.160 > 150.160.150.160: ESP(spi=0xc632be22,seq=0x62), length 136
```

I see the difference between `ESP in UDP SPIs:` and `ESP SPIs:` but don't get what it means.

What should I check o fix to make macOS VPN client work?

Comment: You might get more or better responses at https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here it is solution.
Looks like there is some problems with NAT detection for macOS (I tried several different hosts). So `forceencaps=yes` in the client side `ipsec.conf` solved the issue.